# How often does random.randint generate the same number?

Tags: python, random, integer

I want to generate random integers between 0-9 (inclusive on both ends), but I want to make sure it doesn't often generate the same number consecutively. I plan to use the `randint` function from the `random` module. But I'm not sure if it will be handy. How often does `random.randint` generate the same number?

Comment: Assuming it's random enough, the probability to get the same number twice is 10%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not wrap randint?

```
class MyRand(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.last = None

    def __call__(self):
        r = random.randint(0, 9)
        while r == self.last:
            r = random.randint(0, 9)
        self.last = r
        return r

randint = MyRand()
x = randint()
y = randint()
...
```

Comment: Wow, I completely missed the *avoiding repeated, consecutive generation* part of the question, +1.

Comment: That said, I do feel a generator is a more elegant solution here.

Answer (score 3):

Where [the Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#module-random) say *random* you can assume they mean uniformly random unless stated otherwise (that is, all possible outcomes have equal probability).

In order to generate numbers without consecutive numbers being generated, the simplest option is to make your own generator:

```
def random_non_repeating(min, max=None):
    if not max:
        min, max = 0, min
    old = None
    while True:
        current = random.randint(min, max)
        if not old == current:
            old = current
            yield current
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid duplicates you can use a simple wrapper like this (see [Fisher–Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) for explanations on how this works):

```
def unique_random(choices):
    while True:
        r = random.randrange(len(choices) - 1) + 1
        choices[0], choices[r] = choices[r], choices[0]
        yield choices[0]
```

Example of use:

```
from itertools import islice
g = unique_random(range(10))
print list(islice(g, 100))
```

Comment: It doesn't feel natural to me to use a generator for getting a random number.

Comment: Why are you passing `islice` 100? If you want to have it go to the end, just pass `None`.

Comment: @Lattyware the syntax to get a single random number is cumbersome with a generator.

Comment: @Lattyware: to what end? It's endless.

Comment: @thg435 Derp, wasn't thinking about that one. This is true. Ignore my insanity.

Comment: @robert: the question is about generating a non-repeating _sequence_ of random numbers.

Answer (score 2):

This is easily done without a while loop.

```
next_random_number = (previous_random_number + random.randint(1,9)) % 10
```

Comment: That is such a neat and efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

```
list =[]
x=0
for i in range(0,10):
    while x in list:
        x=random.randint(500,1000)
    list.append(x)
print sorted(list, key=int)
```

Comment: Please, explain your answer.[From review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/10627659).

Comment: Hi, U can use list for generating random numbers and not duplicate